# Need help deriving transfer function of this OpAmp exponential approximation circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm having some trouble working out the transfer function of the below circuit. It's coming from [here](https://hackaday.io/project/181914/gallery#90b9919e5858d9a9020f4ab7aa4d616f). \$R_K\$ is changing in increments of 1k about 8 times. Supposedly if you plot this against an exponential function it approximates it fairly well (<1%). However, when I plot my values with that transfer function I get different results so I'm guessing my math is off.

Or I'm just misunderstanding how the complete circuit from Hackaday works and another element is having the "exponential effect". However, I don't think so due to this paragraph:
"So, I found a way to combine two op amps and a few resistors in such a way that a linear increase in resistance from the keyboard turns into an almost exponential voltage that the oscillator can use. Technically the response is polynomial not exponential, but the polynomial is within a fraction of a percent of a true exponential."

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2T2An.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I couldn't figure out how to get current arrows into the schematic, sorry.

My basic assumptions are:

$$
i_1 = -i_2\\
i_1 = i_P - i_K\\
R_3 = 2*R_4\\
R_2 = 2*R_1\\
$$

and then my math goes like this:

\begin{equation}
i_2 = \frac{(V_O - \frac{V_{in}}{3})}{R_2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
V_P = V_{in} - \frac{V_{in}}{3} - V_{R1} = \frac{2*V_{in}}{3}-i_1*R_1
\end{equation}

\begin{eqnarray*}
i_1 &=& \frac{V_P}{R_P} - \frac{(V_{in}-V_P)}{R_K} \\
&=& \frac{(\frac{2*V_{in}}{3}-i_1*R_1)}{R_P}-\frac{(V_{in}-\frac{2*V_{in}}{3}+i_1*R_1)}{R_K} \\
&=& V_{in} * \frac{(8*R_K-12*R_P)}{(12*R_P*R_K+6*R_2*R_K+2*R_2*R_P)} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

at which point I put everything into \$i_1 = -i_2\$:

\begin{equation}
V_{in} * \frac{(8*R_K-12*R_P)}{(12*R_P*R_K+6*R_2*R_K+2*R_2*R_P)} = \frac{(\frac{V_{in}}{3} - V_O)}{R_2} \\
\ldots \\
\ldots \\
V_O = \frac{V_{in}}{3}*\frac{(2*R_P*R_K-3*R_2*R_K)}{(2*R_P*R_K+R_2*R_K+R_2*R_P)}
\end{equation}

My guess is I mucked something up with the voltage around the op amp inputs since it's not GND, but despite a few approaches (the math above being the last one) I can't figure out where my mistake is. I skipped putting some steps in my math in the post so it stays somewhat compact.

Now, I'm not necessarily looking for a full worked example (although I'll also gladly take that), I'm more than happy if someone can give me a hint where I made a mistake and maybe even explain what that mistake is.

This is my first time asking a question so if I did something wrong (like formatting the formulas in a weird way) please tell me so I can do better next time.

Comment: That specific circuit has nothing non-linear in it, so it will have a linear response until the op-amp reaches its output voltage limit in either direction. Your last equation says it all, vo = vin/3*some_function_of_resistor_values, that function is of course constant. In the circuit you link to, it's the FETs that appear to be doing the non-linear work, as voltage-dependent resistors, which you don't have in your circuit. Great formula formatting for a first-timer BTW!

Comment: *The issue is that this seems to be wrong since, well, it does not approximate an exponential function* Which was my conclusion also after reading the title of your question and looking at the circuit. Assuming that the Opamp can work in proper feedback mode, there are no **non linear** elements in your circuit so it cannot behave in any exponential way. For an exponential / logarithmic circuit I would expect to see a diode for example.

Comment: Ah crap, of course I forgot the most important piece of information. The op amp itself is not specifically approximating the exponential, it's more that resistor R_K is changing depending on which key is pressed. Say there are 8 different keys/resistors. If you then plot the output voltages of the op amp against a true exponential the error is very low (< 1%) and my transfer function does not do that. I think I'll remove the "exponential" thing from the post since it just adds confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a superposition principle to get the "low entropy" equation.

We have to analyze those two circuits:

Case one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foO2Xq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$Vo' = \frac{V_{IN}}{3} \left(1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_P||R_K}\right)$$

Case two:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOR6YD.png)</sup>

$$Vo'' = -V_{IN} \left(\frac{R_K||R_1}{R_P + R_K||R_1} \times \frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)$$

And finally we have:

$$V_O = V_{IN}\left(\frac{1}{3}\left(1 + \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_P||R_K}\right) - V_{IN}\frac{R_K||R_1}{R_P + R_K||R_1} \frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)$$

As you can see we have a differential amplifier.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I did not think of that but your answer completely opened my eyes. Apparently I can't upvote yet, is there some other way I can leave reputation?

Comment: Thx, for your kind words. As for the reputaion, simply answer the people's questions or ask more yourself.